# Tor Browser Automation

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Is there way to pro grammatically click on new identity button in tor browser in Windows as well Linux?

I checked Selenium as well other tools but I want browser extension not external tool as I don't have admin privilege

Comment: When you say "programmatically", you mean you want to control the browser via a script (i.e. a small programme), right? But you want to do this from within a browser extension, rather than run the script from the (external) command line? What were your specific reasons against using Selenium?

Answer (score 1):

Use *any* UI pilot software, not the *in-browser pilots*, like Selenium. The UI pilots are quite common ones since 1990-s, they also called a *macro tools*. The simpliest was called UOLoop, tons of them are free and open source